# Translating a quaternion camera at a fixed height

Tags: 3d, xna, geometry, computational-geometry, xna-4.0

I have a quaternion camera written in C# (shamelessly taken from an online tutorial). I'm trying to translate the position of the camera in world space, which is represented as a Vector3, in the direction the camera is "facing." However, I want the camera to stay at a fixed height in the Y-axis (Assume the camera will never be "upside down", in that it may not be rotated past looking vertically up or down the Y-axis).

Put simply, I want the camera to behave in a similar manner to a camera in a RTS game, such as Command & Conquer. Pressing forward should move you "up" the map, staying at a constant height above the terrain. My naive attempt, given below, is insufficient, as the speed of the camera is determined by the angle the camera looks down on the world.

```
var Y = mPosition.Y;
mPosition += mInverseViewMatrix.Backward * amount;
mPosition.Y = Y;
```

In the above, mPosition is a Vector3 representing the world position. mInverseViewMatrix is the inverse of the view matrix.

I am using XNA and C#, but any general advice regarding quaternion and vector manipulation will probably be of use.

Answer (score 1):

I've handled this in two ways.

1) Use the quaternion to rotate a unit vector pointing 'forward' so that it's pointing the appropriate direction.  Zero-out the **y** component of the vector.  Re-normalize the vector.  Multiply by velocity and add to the current position.

*Edited* 
2) Make a copy of the quaternion.  Zero-out the **x** and **z** components of the quaternion.  Re-normalize the quaternion.  Rotate a unit vector by the quaternion, multiply by velocity, and add to position.  A quaternion representation of rotation is a modified axis-angle representation.  So if you zero-out the 'x' and 'z' portions of the axis around which rotation is happening, then the only rotation remaining is 'yaw' the rotation around the y axis (assuming that 'forward' is aligned with the z-axis).

Comment: I used your second suggestion and it works a treat. It does seem like a bit of an indirect solution, but I'll certainly take that over an incorrect one. Thanks.

Comment: I take that back, I've just realised that this transformation doesn't appear to be stable under rotation about the Y-axis. Maybe I'm going about it wrong, any pointers? var orient = new Quaternion(new Vector3(0, mOrientation.Y, mOrientation.Z), mOrientation.W);
            orient.Normalize();
            var vect = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.UnitX, Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(orient));  // Vector3.UnitX * Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(orient);

            mPosition += vect * amount;

Comment: Oops.  Yeah, you need to zero out **z** as well, leaving only w and x.